# How to completely stop running the code and exit the application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my code, I check if the executable file `op.exe` is in the application run path directory, in case if not, it does show `MsgBox` and exits the application, the problem is that it doesn't really exit the application, because the code after is executing everytime.

Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
    If Not File.Exists("op.exe") Then
        MsgBox("op.exe not found!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Application.Exit()
    End If
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory('files')
```

MsgBox appears, and application does exit, but it's creating the directory `files` afterwards (`IO.Directory.CreateDirectory('files')`) . I dont want that, and I would like to completely close the application after showing the MsgBox.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try `Environment.Exit(0)` instead.

Comment: And don't use File.Exists() like that. Just try to open or use the file, and handle the exception if it fails. Also, you can always just add an `Else` block for the CreateDirectory() call.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn But I don't want to open or use it, I just want to check if it exists. I think using this solution is nothing bad?

Comment: That is okay then, but almost always here when you see someone looking for a file they do this wrong.

Comment: @David If you care, you can post an answer so I could mark it as valid.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `Environment.Exit(0)` instead. [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit.aspx) causes a message loop to exit, but that happens by the message loop reading a "quit" message from its queue. [`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) causes the process itself to exit.